# Create generic type interface but cannot useState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, material-react-table

I have create generic type interface which extends StandardTextFieldProps

```
interface CustomAdvancedProps<T> extends StandardTextFieldProps {
  props: StandardTextFieldProps;
  onRowSelected: (value: T) => void;
  endPoint: string;
  columns: MRT_ColumnDef<any>[];
}
```

When function to implement this

```
function AdvanceTextField<T>({ props, columns, endPoint }: CustomAdvancedProps<T>) {
  const [setTestRow, testRow] = useState<T | null>();

  const modalOnClose = (value: T) => {
    console.log(`Select row: ${value}`);
    if (value != null && value !== undefined) {
      setTestRow(value);
    }
  };
```

I've got error on setTestRow(value);, it said This expression is not callable.
Type '{}' has no call signatures.ts(2349) , Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.ts(2723)

can I know how to fix it ?

Comment: Its being unable to correctly infer the type of ```setTestRow```. This is likely because you're using the ```useState``` hook incorrectly. In your ```CustomAdvancedProps``` interface, you have defined ```props``` as ```StandardTextFieldProps```. However, in your ```AdvanceTextField``` function, you're trying to destructure ```props``` from the function parameters, which is not defined in your function parameters.

Comment: `[setTestRow, testRow]` should be `[testRow,setTestRow]`. You also should probably initialize it to null

Comment: ok thank you , I solve it